Two different xUnit integration tests with the same IClassFixture writes to the same database despite different connection strings
I have a strange problem with some unit tests in a project I'm working on. I'll try to describe the problem as well as I can, but I'm pretty confused as to what's actually happening here.
The project is a standard ASP.NET webapi with EF Core and Quartz for batch operations.
There are two test classes, that both use the same class fixture T and implement the IClassFixture<T> interface. The fixture spins up a local database and generates a connection string that is used to replace the actual db connection string in the configuration of the webapp which is spun up during the tests. This works fine normally.
The problem is that if I run both test classes at once, one of them fails due to a duplicate Quartz job insertion. The project has some scheduled jobs that are added during startup, which gives job name conflicts. We also write logging to the same database for debug purposes. Upon inspection, all startup log statements are duplicated in one of the two newly created databases, indicating that there are two instances of the webapp being spun up by the test framework as expected, but both instances utilize the same connection string.
However, when logging the actual connection string to the database, the connection strings are different, even though both logging statements and any database operations are done towards a single database. Which database of the two it pics is seemingly random, and so is the set of tests that fail.
Moreover, when I try to run both test classes at once but in debug mode, everything is fine and all tests pass. I've also tried fetching and logging the dbContext.ContextId at runtime, which shows 2 different instances of the dbContext being utilized as one would expect. Everything is scoped too, and the scopes are verified to be different.
I'm pretty stuck on how to even approach a problem like this, because nothing makes sense. From what I gather, running the unit tests runs them in parallel whereas debug mode runs them consecutively, but I don't know this for sure or if there are more differences under the hood.

Are you using at least version 3.12? It has fixes for scoping in DI use.

@MarkoLahma thanks, this actually did solve the problem! However, I'm still getting all the logs written to the same database. I'm suspecting the same issue is present in Serilog, which made it seem like everything was using the wrong database but it might be two separate issues with identical results. Eitehr way, logging being written to the wrong database during testing isn't critical to fix, so I'll leave it for now
